# Need Help Understanding C# Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Console Application like this, which is using threads.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void ThreadMethod()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);              
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
            t.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Do some work.");
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            t.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

Output of program is the following:

```
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 0
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 1
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 2
Main thread: Do some work.
ThreadProc: 3
ThreadProc: 4
ThreadProc: 5
ThreadProc: 6
ThreadProc: 7
ThreadProc: 8
ThreadProc: 9
ThreadProc: 10
```

Program executing properly. But I can't understand how this output is generated. How does this program work? I don't have good understanding of threads.

Can someone explain this for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi threading on WIndows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047290/multi-threading-on-windows)

Answer (score 7):

`Main()` is the starting point of your application.

`t.Start()` creates second thread which runs in parallel with main one. From now on code in method `Main` is executed along with method `ThreadMethod`. There is no quarantee in console output order. Change the sleep time and you will see different results.

`t.Join` will hold `Main`'s execution until `ThreadMethod` finishes. Below this line, the program has only single thread and everything will be executed sequentially.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1083/Multithreaded-Programming-Using-C) article, mentioned in the comments, is a good explanation of threading in a C application, but these same principals apply to almost all languages.

[This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MultithreadingIntro10062005000439AM/MultithreadingIntro.aspx) explains threading in C# in more detail.

Comment: Sure that's your privilege. I prefer to try teach. But of course - pointing to an [multithreding tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1083/Multithreaded-Programming-Using-C) I should added too.

Comment: There are clear posts on meta saying you shouldn't downvote legitimate answers to bad questions. Downvote the question, not the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner, if your objective is to understand how `Thread` operates in .NET I would recommend opening up the `Threads` window in Visual Studio and observe your program as it progresses through the procedure.

Instead of debugging your application by pressing `F5`, try pressing `F11` to step into the first line of your code.  It should bring you into debug mode with the procedure paused at the first line.

To open the `Threads` window press `Ctrl + Alt + H` or you can also find it by navigating the menus as follows: `Debug > Windows > Threads`.  This menu is only visible when you are debugging.

As you step through the code you should be able to see the active thread toggle between the first and second thread each time that you call `Thread.Sleep(0);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Threads** are light weight processes in any of the programming language.

Normally, programs are executed as a **Process**. Similarly **Threads** are small processes which is grouped into one **Main Process**.

**For Example** : If a program is executing in system (say a, **Web browser**, the web browser is the process, and within the browser **tabs,http connection,browser rendering** are threads).

Actually, i didnt used threading in `C#`, one day i was using `smtp.send(Mail)` for sending mail. That `send(mail)` tooks upto 5secs of time to execute, because it needs internet connection. so i used separate thread to run this `send()` method outside of **Main()**.

i hope you understand somewhat about **THREADS**.. is it?